# Perform operation on columns based on values of another columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A",1,98,88,"",567,453,545,656,323,756], ["B",1,99,"","",231,232,234,943,474,345], ["C",1,97,67,23,543,458,456,876,935,876], ["B",1,"",79,84,895,237,678,452,545,453], ["A",1,45,"",58,334,778,234,983,858,657], ["C",1,23,55,"",183,565,953,565,234,234]], columns=["id","date","col1","col2","col3","col1_num","col1_deno","col3_num","col3_deno","col2_num","col2_deno"])
```

I need to make Nan/blank values for respective _num and _deno for column name.  Ex: Make values Nan/blank for **"col1_num"** and **"col1_deno"** if particular row of **"col1"** is blank. Repeat the same process for **"col2_num"** and **"col2_deno"** based on **"col2"**, and for **"col3_num"** and **"col3_deno"** based on **"col3"**.

**Expected Output:**

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([["A",1,98,88,"",567,453,"","",323,756], ["B",1,99,"","",231,232,"","","",""], ["C",1,97,67,23,543,458,456,876,935,876], ["B",1,"",79,84,"","",678,452,545,453], ["A",1,45,"",58,334,778,234,983,"",""], ["C",1,23,55,"",183,565,"","",234,234]], columns=["id","date","col1","col2","col3","col1_num","col1_deno","col3_num","col3_deno","col2_num","col2_deno"])
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try with **boolean masking**:

```
# select the columns
c = pd.Index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

# create boolean mask
m = df[c].eq('').to_numpy()

# mask the values in `_num` and `_deno` like columns
df[c + '_num'] = df[c + '_num'].mask(m, '')
df[c + '_deno'] = df[c + '_deno'].mask(m, '')
```

---

```
>>> df

  id  date col1 col2 col3 col1_num col1_deno col3_num col3_deno col2_num col2_deno
0  A     1   98   88           567       453                         323       756
1  B     1   99                231       232                                      
2  C     1   97   67   23      543       458      456       876      935       876
3  B     1        79   84                         678       452      545       453
4  A     1   45        58      334       778      234       983                   
5  C     1   23   55           183       565                         234       234
```

Answer (score 3):

@shubham's answer is simple and to the point and I believe faster as well; this is just an option, where you may not be able to (or want to) list all the columns

Get the list of columns that need to be changed:

```
cols = [col for col in df if col.startswith('col')]

['col1',
 'col2',
 'col3',
 'col1_num',
 'col1_deno',
 'col3_num',
 'col3_deno',
 'col2_num',
 'col2_deno']
```

Create a dictionary pairing col1 to the columns to be changed, same for col2 and so on:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for col in cols:
    if "_" in col:
        d[col.split("_")[0]].append(col)

d

defaultdict(list,
            {'col1': ['col1_num', 'col1_deno'],
             'col3': ['col3_num', 'col3_deno'],
             'col2': ['col2_num', 'col2_deno']})
```

Iterate through the dict to assign the new values:

```
for key, val in d.items():
    df.loc[df[key].eq(""), val] = ""




 id  date col1 col2 col3 col1_num col1_deno col3_num col3_deno col2_num col2_deno
0  A     1   98   88           567       453                         323       756
1  B     1   99                231       232                                      
2  C     1   97   67   23      543       458      456       876      935       876
3  B     1        79   84                         678       452      545       453
4  A     1   45        58      334       778      234       983                   
5  C     1   23   55           183       565                         234       234
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `MultiIndex`:

```
#first convert not processing and testing columns to index
df1 = df.set_index(['id','date'])
cols = df1.columns
#split columns by _ for MultiIndex
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

#compare columns without _ (with NaN in second level) by empty string
m = df1.xs(np.nan, axis=1, level=1).eq('')
#create mask by all columns
mask = m.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1, level=0)
#set new values by mask, overwrite columns names
df1 = df1.mask(mask, '').set_axis(cols, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df1)
  id  date col1 col2 col3 col1_num col1_deno col3_num col3_deno col2_num  \
0  A     1   98   88           567       453                         323   
1  B     1   99                231       232                               
2  C     1   97   67   23      543       458      456       876      935   
3  B     1        79   84                         678       452      545   
4  A     1   45        58      334       778      234       983            
5  C     1   23   55           183       565                         234   

  col2_deno  
0       756  
1            
2       876  
3       453  
4            
5       234
```